# How to maximize a two variable function?

Tags: algorithm, maxima

I know if this were one variable I could easily find the maximum by hand, but I now have two variables to solve for.

I want to maximize `f(x) = delay(v_dd, v_t) * energy(v_dd, v_t)`

Both delay and energy depend on a `I = K_1 * (v_dd - v_t)**2` And v_dd must be between [.3, 1] and v_t = v_dd - .1

What is the general technique to maximize a function of two variables with constraints?

Would the general technique be

```
def edp(v_dd, v_t):
    e_total = v_dd ** 2 + v_dd
    return e_total

fmin(-1*edp)
```

How do I enforce the constraints?

Comment: Asking for code, and especially when doing that for two vastly different languages at the same time, is likely to result in your question getting downvoted and/or closed. I edited the languages out, since it looks like you're looking for an algorithm to implement.

Comment: Gradient descent seems like the way to go?

Comment: The question is not clear for me. If `v_t = v_dd - .1`, then at the end you only have one independent variable

Comment: In general, this is a difficult problem. A web search for "constrained optimization" will turn up some resources. However, in this particular case, you have an equality constraint which turns the problem into a one-dimensional optimization, which is much simpler.